# How to find a subset of a 2d array by selecting rows and columns in c?

Tags: c, select, filter, matrix

In an (m by n) array stored as `double *d`  (column major), what is the fastest way of selecting a range of rows and or columns:

```
double *filter(double *mat, int m, int n, int rows[], int cols[]);
```

invoked as:

```
double *B;
int rows[]= {1,3,5}; int cols[]={2,4};
B = filter(A, 5, 4, rows, cols);
```

which is expected to return a 3-by-2 subset of A consisting of elements (1,2), (1,4), (3,2)...

Comment: What do you mean by 'fastest'? Do you mean 'fastest to implement', 'fastest to compile', or 'fastest to execute'? Most likely, you mean the latter, in which case the answer is: try various techniques and profile each for your target platform. The way you have it coded, filter() will need to allocate memory, so your API is not ideal for run time performance. – William Pursell 0 secs ago  [delete this comment]

Answer (score 2):

c provides no native support for this, so you'll have to find a library that supports it, or define it by hand.

pseudocode:

```
a=length of rows     // no built in c functionality for this either, 
b=length of cols     // use a sentinel, or pass to the function
nmat = allocate (sizeof(double)*a*b) on the heap
for (i=0; i<a; ++i)
   for (j=0; j<b; ++j)
      // Note the column major storage convention here (bloody FORTRAN!)
      nmat[i + j*b] = mat[ rows[i] + cols[j]*n ];
return nmat
// caller responsible for freeing the allocated memeory
```

I've commented on the two big problems you face.

Comment: thanks. i was afraid of that. fortran has its advantages -- but c is called for here. sigh!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that `m` and `n` should be the dimension of the new array (i.e. `m` should be the number of items of `rows` and `n` should be the number of items in cols) and not the dimension of the source array as seems to be the case in your example because a) you don't need to know the dimension of the source array if you already know which indices to pick from it (and are presumably allowed to assume that those will be valid) and b) if you don't know the size of `rows` and `columns` they are useless as you can't iterate over them.

So under that assumption the algorithm could look like this:

- Allocate memory for an m x n array
- For each i in 0..m, j in 0..n
- - `B[i,j] = A[ rows[i], cols[j] ];`

Comment: good points. m & n are dimensions of the source matrix. The interface needs length(rows) & length(cols). In which case m & n are not needed. I am used to fortran where you can pass a vector of integers. My intent with the interface was to copy ith column using something like memcpy((i*n), (i*n), n*sizeof(double)), then the rows are looped over using linear-index. That would require a temporary array. Your approach is direct and easy. Not sure which will be faster. Will end-up profiling. Thanks.